# Android emulator - samsung galaxy y

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I've just started learning android and I've completed the hello world sample program which running on my galaxy tab emulator successfully.

Now i have the following concerns as below

1. can this hello world program run on galaxy y handset?
2. From where I can get the emulator for galaxy y model from samsung?
3. I am using sdk platform 2.2 , can this code run on Android OS v2.3.5 (Gingerbread - real handset)?

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes
2) I'm not sure if such thing exists
3) Yes

You should try running the program on your handset; you can't learn unless you do. just FYI, I had to install Samsung Kies to get the drivers that let Eclipse see a Galaxy tab. I'm not sure if you have to do the same for the handset, but if that's the case, now you know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are beginning to learn Android you are better off learning with the default emulator that comes with the SDK. Setting up handset manufacturer specific emulators is not the hassle to address right now. Just use the default SDK, you will be fine.

Hello world programs, in almost all cases in Android will work with any emulator or SDK (from Android 1.6 onwards). So you should be okay.

Also, if it doesnt run due to some reason, learning how to recognize it and address it is a useful skill too, so dont think its not important.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to Android start your app projects with

```
Minimum required SDK-android 2.2 froyo
Target SDK- 4.2 jelly bean
Compile with android 4.2.
```

After creating the project go to your workspace APP project `folder/bin/.apk` file, copy and paste the .apk file and run it on your Samsung Galaxy y. It works, even I to have a Galaxy y mobile and tried it, it works.

Thank You. :)